# RewriteRule wont work when link contains dash (on loaclhost xampp)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This works for links like:

```
<a href="/subpagewithoutdash">working link (will link to subpagewithoutdash.html)</a>
```

But it doesn't work for links with dash:

```
<a href="/subpage-with-dash">not working link (should link to subpage-with-dash.html)</a>
```

Any idea of how to fix it? I am sitting on a Windows computer with Xampp installed (localhost).

Comment: A link containing a period seems more likely to cause a problem with this rule than one with a dash. Does your real-world problem URL have dashes *and* a period?

Comment: I'm not shore I understand what you mean, but I have added the filenames of the files i am trying to rewrite to... I am trying to get http://www.page.com/subpage to adress http://www.page.com/subpage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can immediately think of two situations would cause this rule not to be applied:

1. `subpage-with-dash` is the name of a directory in the site root. This would trip the `RewriteCond` and cause the rule to be skipped.
2. The URL has a period in it. The pattern in the RewriteRule — `^([^\.]+)$`) — excludes URLs that contain any periods. So, if `subpage-with-dash` is actually `subpage-with-dash.something`, the rule wouldn't apply.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was. I restarted the computer and now it works :S THanks any way.